# EF Core 3.x: duplicate value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following code:

```
public class DeviceVerizon
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string InternalDeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class DeviceVerizonMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DeviceVerizon>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DeviceVerizon> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(DeviceVerizon));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.DeviceId);

        builder.HasIndex(v => v.InternalDeviceId).IsUnique();

        builder.HasOne(o => o.Device)
            .WithOne(o => o.VerizonData)
            .HasForeignKey<DeviceVerizon>(a => a.DeviceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .IsRequired()
            ;
    }
}
```

so, InternalDeviceId is just unique index.

some code change InternalDeviceId for existing record and add new record with the previous InternalDeviceId.
So, `localDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId = 1420531689`

I update it for new (`remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId = '111111111'`)

```
                localDevice.VerizonData = remoteDevice.VerizonData;
                _context.Devices.Update(localDevice);
```

then add new record with `remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId = 1420531689`:

```
                _context.Devices.Add(remoteDevice);
```

and after it I call:

```
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but I get an exception:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.DeviceVerizon' with
> unique index 'IX_DeviceVerizon_InternalDeviceId'. The duplicate key
> value is (1420531689).

The full code:

```
    foreach (var remoteDevice in remoteVerizonDevices)
    {
        var localDevice = allLocalDevicesWithIMEI.Where(a => 
            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.IMEI) 
            && a.VerizonData != null 
            && a.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId == remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId 
            && a.IMSI == remoteDevice.IMSI && a.ICCID == remoteDevice.ICCID) 
            || a.IMEI == remoteDevice.IMEI).FirstOrDefault();

        if (localDevice != null) // device with such imei already exists or IMEI is empty on Verizon, but InternalDeviceId is the same and ICCID with IMSI are the same
        {
            var verizonStatus = remoteDevice.VerizonData.State.ConvertToDeviceStatusFromVerizonStatus();

            var existingRequest = _context.VerizonRequests.Where(a => a.DeviceId == localDevice.Id && a.Result == VerizonRequestResult.Pending).FirstOrDefault();

            if (verizonStatus == DeviceStatus.Active && remoteDevice.IsVerizonLastActiveMoreThanDays(60))
            {
                // existing request for this device does not exist, create new
                if (existingRequest == null)
                {
                    localDevice.Status = DeviceStatus.PendingSuspend;
                    localDevice.DateStatusChanging = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    localDevice.LastStatusChangeSource = DeviceStatusChangeSource.Verizon;
                    // create verizon request to change status, because device is offline more than 60 days
                    verizonSuspensionList.Add(localDevice.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Is Verizon status of device is different than locally?
                if (localDevice.Status != verizonStatus)
                {
                    // check whether we have active verizon request, if not, then
                    if (existingRequest == null)
                    {
                        // device is suspended on suremdm, we should suspend on Verizon
                        if (localDevice.Status == DeviceStatus.Suspended
                            && verizonStatus == DeviceStatus.Active)
                        {
                            if (localDevice.Tablet != null && localDevice.Tablet.TabletGroup.GroupName == SpecialSureMdmGroups.Suspended)
                                verizonSuspensionList.Add(localDevice.Id);
                        }
                        else if (localDevice.Status != DeviceStatus.Suspended && verizonStatus == DeviceStatus.Suspended)
                        {
                            // if device is suspended on verizon, we need to suspend on SureMdm
                            localDevice.Status = DeviceStatus.PendingSuspend;
                            localDevice.DateStatusChanging = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            localDevice.LastStatusChangeSource = DeviceStatusChangeSource.Verizon;
                            if (localDevice.Tablet != null)
                            {
                                localDevice.Tablet.SuspensionDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

                                sureMdmSuspensionList.Add(new Core.Dto.DeviceManagement.SureMdm.SureMdmMoveDeviceToSuspendedGroupDto
                                {
                                    TabletId = localDevice.Tablet.TabletId,
                                    CurrentGroupId = localDevice.Tablet.TabletGroupId
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // other cases that device on verizon has different status, that locally
                            VerizonStatusIsDifferentEvent?.Invoke(
                                remoteDevice: remoteDevice,
                                verizonStatus: remoteDevice.VerizonData.State.ConvertToDeviceStatusFromVerizonStatus(),
                                localStatus: localDevice.Status);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var changes = DeviceIsChanged(remoteDevice, localDevice);
            if (changes != null && changes.Count > 0)
                modifiedDevices.Add((localDevice, changes));

            var continueToUpdate = true;

            // if verizon data does not exist, add it
            if (localDevice.VerizonData == null)
            {
                var existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord = allDeviceVerizons.Where(a => a.InternalDeviceId == remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord != null)
                {
                    DeviceWithTheSameVerizonDeviceIdAlreadyExistsEvent?.Invoke(remoteDevice: remoteDevice,
                        localDevice: existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord.Device,
                        verizonDeviceId: remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId);
                    continueToUpdate = false;
                }
            }

            if (continueToUpdate)
            {
                localDevice.VerizonData = remoteDevice.VerizonData;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.ICCID))
                    localDevice.ICCID = remoteDevice.ICCID;
                localDevice.EID = remoteDevice.EID;
                localDevice.ESN = remoteDevice.ESN;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.IMSI))
                    localDevice.IMSI = remoteDevice.IMSI;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.MDN))
                    localDevice.MDN = remoteDevice.MDN;
                localDevice.MEID = remoteDevice.MEID;
                localDevice.MIN = remoteDevice.MIN;
                localDevice.MSISDN = remoteDevice.MSISDN;
                localDevice.SKU = remoteDevice.SKU;
                localDevice.SyncVerizon = true;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(localDevice.Name))
                    localDevice.Name = localDevice.IMEI;

                if (!localDevice.DeviceModelId.HasValue)
                {
                    var verizonGroup = allVerizonGroups.Where(a => a.VerizonGroupName == remoteDevice.VerizonData.GroupName).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (!verizonGroup.DeviceModelId.HasValue)
                        VerizonGroupIsNotLinkedWithDeviceModelEvent?.Invoke(remoteDevice);
                    else
                        localDevice.DeviceModelId = verizonGroup.DeviceModelId;
                }

                _context.Devices.Update(localDevice);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // validate by Internal Verizon DeviceId
            var existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord = allDeviceVerizons.Where(a => a.InternalDeviceId == remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord != null)
            {
                DeviceWithTheSameVerizonDeviceIdAlreadyExistsEvent?.Invoke(remoteDevice: remoteDevice,
                    localDevice: existingInternalVerizonDeviceIdRecord.Device,
                    verizonDeviceId: remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId);
            }
            else
            {
                // add new record
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.IMEI))
                    remoteDevice.Name = remoteDevice.IMEI;
                else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.VerizonData.PrimaryPlaceOfUseFirstName) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.VerizonData.PrimaryPlaceOfUseLastName))
                    remoteDevice.Name = $"{remoteDevice.VerizonData.PrimaryPlaceOfUseFirstName} {remoteDevice.VerizonData.PrimaryPlaceOfUseLastName}";
                else
                    remoteDevice.Name = Core.Constants.Common.Undefined;

                // set device Model
                var verizonGroup = allVerizonGroups.Where(a => a.VerizonGroupName == remoteDevice.VerizonData.GroupName).FirstOrDefault();
                if (!verizonGroup.DeviceModelId.HasValue)
                    VerizonGroupIsNotLinkedWithDeviceModelEvent?.Invoke(remoteDevice);
                else
                    remoteDevice.DeviceModelId = verizonGroup.DeviceModelId;

                // set device status
                remoteDevice.Status = remoteDevice.VerizonData.State.ConvertToDeviceStatusFromVerizonStatus();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteDevice.VerizonData.CarrierName))
                {
                    var verizonCarrier = allVerizonCarriers.Where(a => a.VerizonCarrierName == remoteDevice.VerizonData.CarrierName).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (verizonCarrier.CarrierId.HasValue)
                        remoteDevice.CarrierId = verizonCarrier.CarrierId;
                    else
                    {
                        // notify that carrier is not found locally
                        LocalCarrierIsNotFoundForNewDeviceEvent?.Invoke(remoteDevice);
                    }
                }

                remoteDevice.SyncVerizon = true;

                _context.Devices.Add(remoteDevice);
                newDevices.Add(remoteDevice);
            }
        }
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

why so? only one record has 1420531689, old was updated for new value (111111111) and it saved in the one transaction... How to do it correctly?

Comment: Could you post your real  controller action code please?

Comment: @Serge I don't have controller/action, it's called via Azure Function.

Comment: Just by the way, when I am coding I have a rule that I should alway see the whole function on my screen without scrolling. When it is getting biger, I separate it in two and so on.

Comment: Nowhere in the full code you pasted are you updating an InternalDeviceId. You are comparing InternalDeviceIds, and invoking events, but nowhere in the scope of that DbContext are you altering an InternalDeviceId.  If that is happening off in some event handler then this is probably an issue with altering data with different DbContexts. Sorry to say, but that code looks like a complete rat's nest of logic.  I would be deeply concerned with a project where the solution involved altering IDs on a record where at first glance it looks like it should just be changing associations between entities.

Comment: @StevePy there is an external IDs, which we get from external resource. Our internal ID is different

Comment: Yes, my point is your code does not include anything like your example: `remoteDevice.VerizonData.InternalDeviceId = '111111111'`. Where in all of that code is InternalDeviceId being set?? There is code that checks for data based on the InternalDeviceId, nothing is setting it/changing it.